# Is it possible to put $x^3+62x^2+620x+1000=0$ into the form $x(Ax+1)(Bx+1)=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have an equation
$$x^3+62x^2+620x+1000 = 0$$
I want to put it into the form
$$x(Ax+1)(Bx+1) = 0$$ 
where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

(I've only managed to put into the form $(x+2)(x+10)(x+50)$, but I don't want it in this form.)

Is it possible to do so? If so how can I know and then proceed to find the equivalent equation in the required form?

Comment: It is not possible because $0$ is  not root of the equation.

Comment: It is not possible. If you expand $x(Ax+1)(Bx+1)$, you get $ABx^3+(A+B)x^2+x$. As you can see, there the coefficient of $x^0$ here is $0$ but it is $1000$ in our original expression.

Answer (score 2):

The initial polynomial $x^3+62x^2+620x+1000$ does not have a root at $x=0$ (at $x=0$ it has a value of $1000$).

The polynomial you are trying to rearrange it to
$$x(Ax+1)(Bx+1)$$
has a root at $x=0$ (since $x$ is a factor), regardless of the values of $A$ and $B$.

The two polynomials have different roots, so there is no way they can be identical to each other, and hence you can't rearrange the initial polynomial to be in that form.

Answer (score 1):

The form you want is indeed impossible. Let's use the factor theorem to prove it.
The factor theorem states that if $(x-a)$ is a factor of $f(x)$ then $f(a)=0$.
In your supposed factorised form we have $(x-0)(etc)=0$ which should imply that $f(0)=0$.
Let's try this out:
$f(0)=0+0+0+1000=1000$ NOT $0$ so the above form must be wrong. Hope that helped!